# Looking for a mysql query to count all rows previous to last month

Tags: mysql, date

I'll skip the "why" for brevity.  But if you want to know you can ask.  But basically my first quest was to find a way to count all the rows previous to the current month.  I found the solution to this that works, which is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable 
WHERE log_date < (CURDATE() -  DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()))
```

I just subtract the number of days that has transpired this month and count all rows with date less than the first day of this month.

The next problem is that I need to count all rows before last month.  I guess technically I could take my result above and query for results of last month and subtract the two queries.  But I was hoping for a single query for this.  I have tried variations of the two versions below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable 
WHERE log_date < ((CURDATE()- DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable 
WHERE log_date < DATE_SUB((CURDATE()- DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Both of these approaches along with some variations of this I have tried yield a result of 0 when I know that the answer should be 14.

Is there a way to get the answer I am looking for in a single query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `myTable` WHERE `log_date` BETWEEN "2010-11-01 00:00:00" AND "2010-11-30 23:59:59"
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. It gave me an idea. Since there are no records before a certain date, I could use as a start date something like '2010-01-01' and then would just need to manipulate the end date.  But since this will be used in a loop I need to be able to manipulate the end date with a variable.  That is why using a variation of 'INTERVAL 1 MONTH' would be so useful.  I could change that interval to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I get what you want.

You have 2 dates and want the `COUNT` for records before each date.

```
SELECT
SUM(IF(log_date<DATESUB(CURDATE()-DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())), 1, 0)) AS LAST_MONTH,
SUM(IF(log_date<DATE_SUB((CURDATE()-DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())),INTERVAL 1 MONTH),1,0) 
AS PREV_MONTH
FROM ....
WHERE log_date < DATESUB(CURDATE() - DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()));
```

This way you have 2 emulated `COUNT`s by using `SUM` combined with `IF`.

I'm assuming you are using *MySQL* but this could work on other *DBMS*

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like this and really wanted it to work.  I'm getting a syntax error on that first part "SUM(IF...LAST_MONTH,"  when I take that out it will give count on the second. But the answer it gives is '0' just like in the queries that I had constructed.  Is it possible that it is only counting the rows for that one previous month, because the answer to that would be '0'.  But I need it to count all previous months.

Comment: I fixed the first line.  It didn't need the DATE_SUB on that SUM because there were no factors for subtracting.  The result for the LAST_MONTH is correct (36), but PREV_MONTH should return 14 and returns 0.

Comment: I have narrowed down what it doesn't like.  If I take out " -DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) "  it counts correctly for this case.  It returns 14.  But if I understand correctly, without that it will count everything previous to one month ago from today.  It must only count everything previous to the first of last month.  So is there another way to tell it to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  Thank you goreSplatter and ajreal and dcestari for you input and helping me think through it.  Here is the working query:

`$query = mysql_query("SELECT 
SUM(IF(log_date<(CURDATE()-DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())),1,0)) AS LAST_MONTH,
SUM(IF(log_date<DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY),1,0)) AS PREV_MONTH
FROM myTable WHERE member_id = '$mid'")or die(mysql_error());`

For PREV_MONTH calculation I went back two months, got the last day of that month and added one day to get the first day of last month.  Seems like if they have a "LAST_DAY" they would also have a 'FIRST_DAY' function.

Hope this will serve to help someone down the road.